# A specific charger causing yellow sparks

Tags: electrical, adapter

I just got a new speaker for my Desktop

The charger on first contact in the power strip caused a yellow spark, in the power surge (power strip)
I initially thought it was the power strip

I tried to plug the charger directly in the outlet
Again a yellow spark on first contact, but never again

Can this adapter be causing the problem, or is it the outlet, or the surge protector
Note the surge protector is new, and I never had this issue from this outlet before

Please advise

edited:
the country is Canada, if this helps

Regards
Ali

Comment: If you let the charger sit, unplugged, for several minutes and try it again do you see another spark? That is a common issue, typically caused by a high inrush current due to capacitors charging. A short interval unplugged will not allow them to discharge fully, hence no spark.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because device usage is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: i am testing this,
it happened 3 times in total within 30 minutes
twice on the outlet, once on the power strip

i am mainly worried because its a yellow spark
and i heard a yellow spark is never ok 

i tried other mobile chargers, on the same outlet no issue 

is it the speaker adapter, is it broken, should i return it
or is it the outlet 

does it make sense if its the outlet , that it also happens to the power strip
i am really worried, should i return the speaker or the power strip

what should i do?

Comment: @isherwood 

Hi

I am not asking to fix, the device, I want t isolate the issue
Is it the outlet the surge

Or can it be just the adapter
Also, where can I ask, if this is not the correct forum

Comment: Outlets can't _surge_ unless there's a massive service problem.

Comment: @isherwood so you think its just a faulty adapter, do you recommend i return the speakers? 

by the way, when i said surge, i mean the power strip/surge protector

Comment: If other adapters don't spark at outlet, then the new adapter is faulty, not the outlet/power strip.

Comment: just stop unplugging and re-pluging it, problem solved.

Comment: If it makes you more comfortable you can use a switched outlet or strip. Plug in the adapter while the switch is off, then switch it on. The spark won't be gone, it will just be pitting the switch contacts rather than the outlet. Depending on the design of the switch you may or may not notice the arcing.

Comment: No-one has yet mentioned what type of plug/socket, what country, what voltage. If anything ever sparks on insert in the UK, you send the darn thing right back & get a refund. Is this more prevalent in other territories? Comments so far seem to think it's *almost* acceptable.

Comment: the country is canada
and also if it makes a difference, the speakers are turned off while plugging

Comment: Many devices arc on connect--you just can't always see it because it's tiny. A good example is my laptop charger, which apparently has some fairly large capacitance built in (as also evidenced by the delay in the LED going out after unplugging). This does not necessarily indicate a problem. But, the question is off topic here.

Comment: Although I believe this should be left open so others can find it (I believe similar questions have been asked before) and since the op has not accepted an answer we need to clear unresolved questions.

Answer (score 3):

Others have tried to explain but the spark is not unusual.

Is there anything you can do to prevent the spark from happening?
yes, you could turn the breaker off and plug it in then turn the breaker back on.

The load will still cause a spark but you won’t see it inside the breaker and because breakers snap closed or open the duration will be shorter.

When power adapters sit the capacitors discharge with time and when first plugging in there is a large current draw.

For those that purchased high end transformer based supplies these can also spark because the transformer has to come up and it has filter capacitors also.

The fact that it is sparking means it is drawing current. Lower current devises draw less current and you may not see the spark unless you turn the lights off.

This is nothing to worry about if the transformer powers the speakers and things sound good it probably means that that supply can power a fair size load.

So if it works don’t sweat it nothing is wrong. If your speakers howl with 60 hz you could have a bad filter cap but that’s about it.

Comment: Thanks Ed for the reply
My main concern was that the spark was yellow
not blue 

And i read online, yellow is never ok
Also the speaker was turned off

Comment: Just energizing a small transformer with no load on it will draw current...

Comment: It sounds like you may be getting sparks confused with flames. Sparks are typically yellow - that's fine. **Gas flames** are normally blue - indicating complete combustion. Gas flames that have significant yellow or orange are a sign of incomplete combustion, which is a big problem.

Comment: @Ali I did a quick Google search and found a couple of people saying that for a car's spark plug, a blue spark is good and a yellow spark is bad. However, a power outlet is not a spark plug! When you read that web page that said that a yellow spark is never okay, was the web page talking about spark plugs or outlets? If it was talking about spark plugs, then you can ignore that advice, because it is irrelevant.

Comment: my sources on spark color are

https://www.artplumbingandac.com/electrical/what-causes-sparking-outlets/ 
https://myelectrictoday.com/what-to-do-when-your-outlet-sparks/
https://teagueelectric.com/sparking-outlets-really-dangerous/

Comment: OMG. Don't trust that page *at all*. They are (trying to) selling electrician services. But a *ton* of disinformation. Overloads don't cause sparking - they either cause *overheating and burning* or (if everything is done right) breaker trips. Blue sparks? Never heard of it before this. Plenty of other strange things too - clickbait, sales push, ugh.

Comment: That is a total scam + I bet we can and have solved 99% of anything on that web site. The voltage, current and even the atmosphere around a electrical arc will affect the color. And yes there are some real professionals on here.